# Squid block site except for some pages

Tags: squid

I have Squid proxy server installed on my machine. I created a file `/etc/squid/block.acl`, where all the bad domains are written. And added the following statement to squid.conf:

```
acl bad_url url_regex "/etc/squid/block.acl"
http_access deny bad_url
```

Suppose, there is a domain: finam.ru. I want to block access to all its pages, except for these pages: `finam.ru/analysis/*`

How to do it? I tried regexp, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a file `/etc/squid/white.acl`
2. Put the following data there:

   > ```
   > finam.ru/analysis/.*
   > finam.ru/.*\.js
   > finam.ru/.*\.css
   > ```
3. Put this code into `squid.conf`. You have to put the whitelist before the blacklist:

   > ```
   > acl good_url url_regex "/etc/squid/white.acl"
   > http_access allow good_url
   >
   > acl bad_url url_regex "/etc/squid/block.acl"
   > http_access deny bad_url
   > ```